# slidetoggle vertical menu: Children not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/XZTPZ/) Is vertical menu i have made.

**jQuery-**

```
 $(function(){
    $('.menu-header ul li a',this).click(function(){
      $('li').parent().children('li').children('a').siblings('p',this).slideToggle(100);
    });
});
```

When i try to toggle children element `<p>` it opens all the `<p>` children elements in document. I want to open only children of its parent.

Comment: instead of using  $('li').parent().children('li')... use $(this).. you are selecting it all..

Answer (score 1):

If you need to toggle a sibling `<p>` element, just use the following:

```
$(".menu-header ul li a").click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings("p").slideToggle(100);
    // or  .next("p"). ...

    e.preventDefault(); // to prevent default anchor functionality
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XZTPZ/2/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open only the child of the parent of the `a` clicked you can use `next`. Try with:

```
$('.menu-header ul li a',this).click(function(){      
     $(this).next("p").slideToggle(100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below jquery code

```
         $(function(){
                $('.menu-header ul li a').click(function(){
                     $(this).siblings().slideToggle(100);
               });  
              });
```